# dynamically display photos form local drive to crystal report based on roll number

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I want to dynamically display students photo form local drive folder to crystal report based on their roll number available in sql server database . Roll number and photo file name are same.. My advance thanks those who helping me for my request.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As far as i knew:

```
1. insert the blob file into database.
2. use crystal report wizard(after established the odbc connection or any).
3. create a command.
4. put your query in there(crystal wizard command).
5. use parameter(optional).
6. Done.
```

Comment: Really thanks for your response.. as I am new for CR, can you send and tutorial or web link relevant to my problem.. because your answer is very short.. experience person can understand.. but i couldn't.. thank you once again..